# query is too old and response timeout expired or query ID is in (truncated...) telegram bot api

Tags: php, api, bots, telegram

i had error for telegram inline query answer :

> [08-Jul-2021 15:27:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://api.telegram.org/botToken/answerInlineQuery?callback_query_id=4390353335715218133&results%5Btype%5D=article&results%5Bid%5D=d&results%5Btitle%5D=test&results%5Binput_message_content%5D%5Bmessage_text%5D=salam` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
> {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: query is too old and response timeout expired or query ID is in (truncated...)
> in /home1/nlitlogi/public_html/telegram/project/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113

and my php code :

```
$bot->answerInlineQuery(
['results' => [
  'type' => 'article',
  'id' => 'd',
  'title' => 'test',
  'input_message_content' => [
  'message_text' => 'salam',               ]
]]);
```

`callback_query_id` is `$update->inline_query->id` in my library (sobot : https://github.com/hiradsajde/sobot)

how can i solve this error?